# Use PHP to populate the images and names of the images into this slideshow code

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I'm struggling to create a php gallery slideshow and was hoping someone could recommend how to do this part..

The below code is taken from w3schools and works well, however I'd like to populate the srcs of the image tags using images stored in a folder. I have a folder full of images and I'd like to pull these into the slideshow and use the names of each image file as a title.

For example...

Instead of this:

```
  <div class="mySlides">
    <div class="numbertext">4 / 6</div>
      <img src="img_lights_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>
```

DO THIS:

```
<div class="mySlides">
   <div class="numbertext">4 / 6</div>
   <img src="**CODE TO PULL EACH IMAGE FROM A LOCAL FOLDER eg. 1.jpg then 2.jpg then 3.jpg**" style="width:100%">
   <h2> **Name of the slide taken from the file name e.g.Apples, Bananas, Oranges**</h2>
</div>
```

---

W3SCHOOLS CODE:

HTML:

```
<!-- Container for the image gallery -->
<div class="container">

  <!-- Full-width images with number text -->
  <div class="mySlides">
    <div class="numbertext">1 / 6</div>
      <img src="img_woods_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides">
    <div class="numbertext">2 / 6</div>
      <img src="img_5terre_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides">
    <div class="numbertext">3 / 6</div>
      <img src="img_mountains_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides">
    <div class="numbertext">4 / 6</div>
      <img src="img_lights_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides">
    <div class="numbertext">5 / 6</div>
      <img src="img_nature_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides">
    <div class="numbertext">6 / 6</div>
      <img src="img_snow_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <!-- Next and previous buttons -->
  <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
  <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>

  <!-- Image text -->
  <div class="caption-container">
    <p id="caption"></p>
  </div>

  <!-- Thumbnail images -->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="img_woods.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(1)" alt="The Woods">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="img_5terre.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(2)" alt="Cinque Terre">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="img_mountains.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(3)" alt="Mountains and fjords">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="img_lights.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(4)" alt="Northern Lights">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="img_nature.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(5)" alt="Nature and sunrise">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="img_snow.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(6)" alt="Snowy Mountains">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* Position the image container (needed to position the left and right arrows) */
.container {
  position: relative;
}

/* Hide the images by default */
.mySlides {
  display: none;
}

/* Add a pointer when hovering over the thumbnail images */
.cursor {
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev,
.next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: -50px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
.prev:hover,
.next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

/* Number text (1/3 etc) */
.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

/* Container for image text */
.caption-container {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #222;
  padding: 2px 16px;
  color: white;
}

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

/* Six columns side by side */
.column {
  float: left;
  width: 16.66%;
}

/* Add a transparency effect for thumnbail images */
.demo {
  opacity: 0.6;
}

.active,
.demo:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

JS:

```
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

// Next/previous controls
function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

// Thumbnail image controls
function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
  var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
  captionText.innerHTML = dots[slideIndex-1].alt;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try that :

```php
$directory = "/images";
$images = glob($directory . "/*.jpg");
$image_list_1 = "";
$i = 0

foreach($images as $image)
{
    $image_list_1 .= '<div class="mySlides fade"><div class="numbertext">'.$i.' / '.count($images).'</div><img src="'.$image.'" style="width:100%"><div class="text">Caption Text</div></div>';
}

 <!-- Slideshow container -->
<div class="slideshow-container">

  <!-- Full-width images with number and caption text -->
  <?=$image_list_1?>

  <!-- Next and previous buttons -->
  <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
  <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
</div>
<br>

<!-- The dots/circles -->
<div style="text-align:center">
<?php
foreach ($images as $key => $value) { 
    echo '<span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide('.($key+1).')"></span>'; 
    echo "\n";
}   
?>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, that's pretty much what I ended up doing - nice to know I went the right way about it! :)